# using graph API trying to get statuses

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get user status updates using the graph API.

These are my steps

1. The user grants me user_status,read_stream permission
2. then my app does the following.

   1. `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=".$FBappID."&client_secret=".$FBappSecret`
      and get the $AccessToken
   2. next i goto `https://graph.facebook.com/the-username/permissions?access_token=$AccessToken`
   3. i make sure read_stream and user_status = 1
   4. then i try `https://graph.facebook.com/the-username/statuses?access_token=$AccessToken`

when i do this i get the error " failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First to get the token from facebook, the url must set like

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[App_id]&redirect_uri=http://[you app uri]/url/where_you_recive_the_token_from facebook
```

This will redirect something like:

```
http://you_app_uri/url/?code=[Code Generated By Facebook String(196)]
```

Then you can used

```
https://graph.facebook.com/the-username/statuses?access_token=$_GET['code']
```

Comment: Does this mean , the use has to login each time?
My users want to just update FB and their updates appear on mysite.

Comment: If the user is already login in facebook, this will auto redirect to the http://you_app_uri/url/?code=[CODE], but if the user not will ask credentials